# Using Ito's formula to calculate higher moments of the Wiener process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

We have the $q$-th moment of the one-dimensional Wiener process at each time $t$:

$m_q(t)=E((W(t,.))^q)$, $q=1,2,...,t \geq 0$.

I am trying to prove that

$m_q(t)=\frac{1}{2}q(q-1)\left(\int_{0}^{t} m_{q-2}(s)ds\right)$ for all $q \geq 2$ and $t \geq 0$.

Is there an elegant way of showing this?

Comment: From the geometric Brownian motion we know that $E(e^{aW_t})=e^{a^2t/2}$. Now expand both sides in $a$ and compare coefficients of equal degree...

Comment: What prevents you from analyzing $e^{aW_t}$ using Ito's formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed an elegant way to prove this. To that effect, I give you the following two hints.

**Hint 1**: Find suitable $g(x)$ to apply Itô's formula to.

> **Edit** Let $g(x) = x^q$ then $dg(x) = \frac{1}{2}q(q-1)x^{q-2}dt + qx^{q-1}dW_t$ or in integral form $$g(x) = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^tq(q-1)x^{q-2}ds + \int_0^tqx^{q-1}dW_s$$

**Hint 2**: Consider the behavior of Itô integrals under expectation.

> **EDIT** Evaluate  $$\mathbb{E}[g(x)] = \mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{2}\int_0^tq(q-1)x^{q-2}ds + \int_0^tqx^{q-1}dW_s]$$

If you need further help comment below your difficulties.

Comment: Thank you for your response! What I am struggling with is using Ito's formula to find the SDE that satisfies g(X) = X^q, where X = W. Once I show this, I understand that I can simply take the expectation of the resulting integral

Comment: If we set $g(x,t) = g(x) = x^q$ then what does Itô's formula say about $dg(x)$?

Comment: What I have so far is $\frac{dg(x)}{dt}=qx^{q-1}a+\frac{1}{2}q(q-1)x^{q-2}b^2$. Am I on the right track? If so, what should I do with the coefficients, $a$ and $b$?

Comment: I have edited the answer, perhaps it will become clearer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I see what I was doing wrong now!

Comment: Shouldn't there be a $\frac{1}{2}$ in front of the $q(q-1)$ term?

Comment: Yes, nice catch. I have amended the answer.